# Master theorem with logn

Tags: master-theorem

Here's a [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQPVa.jpg).

[image]

I am really confused about the `c` being equal to `0.5` part. Actually overall I am confused how the `logn` can become `n^(0.5)`. Couldn't I just let `c` be equal to `100` which would mean `100 < d` which results in a different case being used? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You of course *could* set `c = 100` so that `n^c` is a (very, veeery) rough asymptotical upper bound to `log(n)`, but this would give you a horrendous and absolutely useless estimate on your runtime `T(n)`.

What it tells you, is that: every polynomial function `n^c` grows faster than the logarithm, no matter how small `c` is, as long as it remains positive. You could take `c=0.0000000000001`, it would seem to grow ridiculously small in the beginning, but at some point it would become larger than `log(n)` and diverge to infinity much faster than `log(n)` does. Therefore, in order to get rid of the `n^2 log(n)` term and being able to apply the polynomial-only version of the Master theorem, you upper bound the logarithmic term by something that grows slowly enough (but still faster than `log(n)`). In this example, `n^c` with `c=0.5` is sufficient, but you could also take `c=10^{-10000}` "just to make sure".

Then you apply the Master theorem, and get a reasonable (and sharp) asymptotic upper bound for your `T(n)`.

Comment: Do you mean upper bounding the n^c?

Comment: No. You have `log(n)` term in your formula. You want to get rid of it, and get some *nice* (means: asymptotically negligible) polynomial instead of `n^2 log(n)`. So you use `n^c` with a sufficiently small `c` as upper bound for `log(n)`, so that the second summand is bounded by `n^{2+c}`. Then you keep proving stuff about `8T([n/2]) + n^{2+c}` using the master theorem.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes total sense now! Thank you so much!